# Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)

Tags: ios, swift

When I run my Simulator, the following error appears as an alert:

> The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (LaunchServicesError error 0.)

I have tried so many answers on Stack Overflow, but they are not working for me.

Here is an image of my `Info.plist`:

[image]

This is my error message in the `CoreSimulator.log`:

> Feb 18 14:48:12  com.apple.dt.Xcode[32825] : Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={Error=MissingBundleExecutable, ErrorDescription=Bundle at path /Users/annabellesykes/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C79A7127-C8EE-454F-B461-D377DA91BF87/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.dnkNTH/extracted/Shailene Woodley Fans.app has missing or invalid CFBundleExecutable in its Info.plist}

This happened straight after I re-added the App Transport Security setting after replacing the other one.

Comment: Did you try to quit from Xcode and simulators as well? It usually happens to me and I can solve with this

Comment: @LucaD I tried this, but sadly it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is telling you the truth.  You don't have a CFBundleExecutable key in your plist.  When you're not showing raw keys, it appears as "Executable file".

Try adding it with the value `$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)`.